# -bash: /usr/local/php5/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, homebrew

I run **curl** I got

```
-bash: /usr/local/php5/bin/curl: No such file or directory
```

When I run 
**which curl** I got

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

When I run **/usr/bin/curl --version** I got

```
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) libcurl/7.49.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

What should I do to be able to run just `curl` again ?

---

I never understand much about this **export** stuffs.

Can someone please shed a little light on this ?

If I run 
**export -p**

```
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8nDQkuFrwz/Render"
declare -x DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.rRmvUm9NdX/unix_domain_listener"
declare -x DISPLAY="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.cw926giJNa/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"
declare -x HOME="/Users/bheng"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="bheng"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/Users/bheng/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
declare -x PWD="/Users/bheng"
declare -x SECURITYSESSIONID="186a6"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.afZzV5wsc3/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="377"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="790013ED-2C1D-4D5E-9BC2-DF773A8473A8"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/54/y_678c6n7q7_pgk1v5lkzwnr0000gp/T/"
declare -x USER="bheng"
declare -x XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
declare -x XPC_SERVICE_NAME="0"
declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F6:0x0:0x0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your $PATH has /usr/bin in it, which is where you're finding curl, you should be fine.

Can you run alias to see if it's being overridden somewhere.

```
alias curl
```